# Can jPlayer be integrated with the Video module?

Tags: files

With the [Video module](http://drupal.org/project/video), the admin panel shows a large list of video formats with dropdowns allowing the user to select one of the supported players. The list that is included consists of:

- Divx
- Quicktime
- RealMedia
- FLV flash
- SWF flash
- Director/Shockwave
- Windows Media
- Theora

I installed the [jPlayer module](http://drupal.org/project/jplayer) and put the jPlayer library into /sites/all/libraries. Is there an established way to get jPlayer to appear in this list, or to otherwise integrate Video with jPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can help you

First of all.

The jplayer you have installed

here is a tutorial that will help get up and running with that [Jplayer Tutorial](http://www.modulesunraveled.com/video)

Second of all, the video module you have, Is for making a new filefield with a new content type, make a view that shows the filefield. 
You should either choose one of the following options. and not both of them.

Hope this helps. I am currently myself working on something smiliar.

I would also like to help you by showing you this link

Its a Drupal distribution called Octopus : [Octupus Drupal](http://octopusvideo.org/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I already have jPlayer and Video installed. jPlayer is not in the dropdown on the Video configuration page though. I'm planning to write a patch to add it.